# Oracle sql how to get the date of a week

Tags: oracle, datetime

I have the following query that gets the week of a date:

```
SELECT   pdm.serie, rta.matricula_ant, TO_CHAR (fecha, 'ww') semana,
         SUM (rta.kms_acumulados) kms,
           COUNT
              (DISTINCT (CASE
                    WHEN v.secuencia BETWEEN rta.sec_origen AND rta.sec_destino
                       THEN v.cod_inc
                    ELSE '0'
                 END
                )
              )
         - 1 numincidencias
    FROM (SELECT ms.tren, ms.fecha_origen_tren, ms.secuencia, ri.cod_inc
            FROM r_incidencias ri, mer_sitra ms
           WHERE ri.cod_serv = ms.tren
             AND ri.fecha_origen_tren = ms.fecha_origen_tren
             AND ri.cod_tipoin IN (SELECT cod_tipo_iincidencia
                                     FROM v_tipos_incidencias
                                    WHERE grupo = '45')
             AND ri.punto_desde = ms.cod_estacion) v,
         r_trenes_asignar rta,
         r_maquinas rm,
         planificador.pl_dh_material pdm
   WHERE rta.fecha BETWEEN TO_DATE ('21/09/2018', 'dd/mm/yyyy') AND TO_DATE ('21/09/2018',
                                                                  'dd/mm/yyyy'
                                                                 )
     AND rta.serie >= 4000
     AND rta.matricula_ant IS NOT NULL
     AND rm.matricula_maq = rta.matricula_ant
     AND rm.cod_serie = pdm.id_material
     AND rta.grafico BETWEEN pdm.desde AND pdm.hasta
     AND v.tren(+) = rta.tren
     AND v.fecha_origen_tren(+) = rta.fecha
GROUP BY pdm.serie, rta.matricula_ant, TO_CHAR (fecha,  'ww')
ORDER BY pdm.serie, rta.matricula_ant, TO_CHAR (fecha, 'ww')
```

For example week 1

I want to display

week 1 :  1 january - 7 january

How can I get this?

Answer (score 2):

Oracle offers [the `TRUNC(datestamp, format)` function](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions201.htm) to manipulate dates this way. You may use a [variety of format strings](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions230.htm#i1002084) to get the first day of a quarter, year, or even the top of the hour.

Given a particular datestamp value, Oracle returns midnight on the first day of the present week with this expression:

```
  TRUNC(datestamp,'DY')
```

You can add days to a datestamp. Therefore this expression gives you midnight on the last day of the week

```
  TRUNC(datestamp,'DY') + 6
```

A WHERE-clause selector for all rows in the present week might be this.

```
  WHERE datestamp >= TRUNC(SYSDATE,'DY')
    AND datestamp < TRUNC(SYSDATE,'DY') + 7
```

Notice that the end of the range is just before (`<`) midnight on the first day of the next week. You need that because you may have datestamps after midnight on the last day of the week. (Beware using `BETWEEN` for datestamp ranges.)

And,

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TRUNC(SYSDATE,'DY'),'YYYY-MM-DD'),
       TO_CHAR(TRUNC(SYSDATE,'DY')+6,'YYYY-MM-DD')
  FROM DUAL;
```

displays the first and last dates of the present week in ISO-like format.

Date arithmetic is cool. It's worth your trouble to study the date-arithmetic functions in your DBMS at least once a year.

Comment: Nice answer, just wanted to add - it sounds like the OP wants `'FMdd month'` as the format string instead of `'YYYY-MM-DD'`. And then to concat them together.

Comment: Note, result of `TRUNC (..., 'DY')` depends on current user session `NLS_TERRITORY`  setting. Use 'IW' to get first day of week according to ISO 8601.